# Django Rest Framework Permissions List Issues in ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to check multiple permissions classes in the `get_permissions` method of a ModelViewSet but even though the `has_object_permission` returns false on all of the classes in the list I'm still able to perform the action.

Here's my get_permissions method:

```
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.action in ("retrieve", "list",):
        permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    elif self.action in ("update", "partial_update", "destroy",):
        permission_classes = [IsOwner | IsAdminUser]
    else:
        permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

On an `update` IsOwner returns True for `has_permission` and False for `has_object_permission` but even a non-admin can make updates.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?